# What is a proper way to re-order the values of a list inside a list?

Tags: python, list, reorderlist

I would like to re-order the values of the lists inside `a_list`.

**This is my current snippet:**

```
a_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
order = [1, 0, 2]

a_list = [a_list[i] for i in order] 

print(a_list)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
[['b', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access each sublist of `a_list`, and then reorder within that sublist. Using list comprehension, it would be like:

```py
a_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
order = [1, 0, 2]

a_list = [[sublst[i] for i in order] for sublst in a_list]

print(a_list) # [['b', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'c']]
```

Your current code reorders the sublists themselves; i.e., for example, if you started with

```
a_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

then the result would have been

```
[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: Glad it helped. In my opnion it's good to get accustomed with nested list comprehensions.

Comment: @Andalusia, I agree with j1-lee lists comprehensions are very powerful and in my opinion easier, once one gets used to them.

Comment: @j1-lee now what if the lists inside `a_list` have different lengths?

Comment: @Andalusia Then you would need to specify an order for each sublist. `[1, 0, 2]` wouldn't apply for a sublist with length 2 or 4. In that case, using `zip` would work. Or, defining a function as in marmeladze might be easier to read, now that the code becomes lengthier.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find a solution for a sublist in `a_list`. So you'll  be able to map that solution to `a_list` elements.

```
def reorder(xs, order):
    # I am omitting exceptions etc. 
    return [xs[n] for n in order]
```

Then you can safely map (comprehend) this function to list of lists.

`[reorder(xs, order) for xs in a_list]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this,

```py
import copy

a_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
order = [1, 0, 2]

lis = copy.deepcopy(a_list)

ind = 0
for i in range(len(a_list)):
    ind = 0
    for j in order:
        lis[i][ind] = a_list[i][j]
        ind += 1

a_list = lis

print(a_list)
```

This maybe not the most appropriate solution,
But I think you can do it like this.
Thank you
Best of luck